# What are good reasons for a budget extension?

Tags: funding

What are some reasons that could justify a no-cost budget extension for grant received from a funding agency and possibly reasons that don't?

Comment: Is this the same as a cost-neutral project extension? If so, it would mainly depend on what kind of budget you have left. (Staff, investments, machines/equipment...)

Comment: @JayFromA "no cost" = no additional funding.

Comment: Answer probably depends on the funder.

Comment: @StrongBad I don't see a how funding agencies will differ

Comment: Can you provide context?

Comment: @ThomasLeeth because the [NIH](https://era.nih.gov/Commons/Commons/status/NCE.htm) basically does not require any reasons, but industry or charity funders are going to want to know why.

Comment: @user2768 a grant received from a funding agency to support academic research

Comment: @ThomasLee, I don't understand why a funding agency would want a "no-cost budget extension." There's no cost, so continue the research without further funding.

Comment: The "no cost" in no cost extension really means "no additional cost."  You're asking for permission to keep spending from the budget after the originally scheduled end of the project.

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes, no additional cost https://osp.mit.edu/grant-and-contract-administration/managing-projects/no-cost-extensions